# Not sure why int value is not what it is supposed to be

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

[image]I'm solving this problem : https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/structuring-the-document/problem

When I run my program on my IDE (XCode) I can see that `word_count  int 7428912` is not what it is supposed to be for any input. I am not sure why. I know that I am accessing out of bounds array index but I need someone to show me where exactly. The program outputs correctly and then gives an error. `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x73696870)`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#define MAX_CHARACTERS 1005
#define MAX_PARAGRAPHS 5

struct word {
    char* data;
};

struct sentence {
    struct word* data;
    int word_count;//denotes number of words in a sentence
};

struct paragraph {
    struct sentence* data  ;
    int sentence_count;//denotes number of sentences in a paragraph
};

struct document {
    struct paragraph* data;
    int paragraph_count;//denotes number of paragraphs in a document
};
#include <ctype.h>
struct document get_document(char* text) {


    int spaces = 0, periods = 0, newlines = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
        if(text[i] == ' ')
            spaces++;
        else if(text[i] == '.')
            periods++;
        else if(text[i] == '\n')
            newlines++;


    struct document doc;
    doc.paragraph_count = newlines + 1;
    doc.data = malloc((newlines + 1) * sizeof(struct paragraph));

    int inBetweenPeriods = 0, j = 0;
    struct paragraph para[doc.paragraph_count];
    for(int i = 0; i < doc.paragraph_count; i++) {
        for(; j < strlen(text); )
            if(text[j] == '.') {
                inBetweenPeriods++;
                j++;
            }
            else if(text[j] == '\n' || j == strlen(text) - 1) {
                para[i].sentence_count = inBetweenPeriods;


                j++;
                break;
            }
            else
                j++;

        para[i].data = malloc((inBetweenPeriods) * sizeof(struct sentence));
        inBetweenPeriods = 0;
    }

    struct sentence sen[periods];
    int sp[periods];
    for(int j = 0; j < periods; j++)
        sp[j] = 0;
    int beg = 0;
    int ij = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < strlen(text); j++) {
        if(text[j] == '.') {
            for(int k = beg; k < j; k++)
                if(text[k] == ' ')
                    sp[ij]++;
            ij++;
            beg = j + 1;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < periods; i++) {

        sen[i].word_count = sp[i] + 1;//spaces + 1;
        sen[i].data = malloc((sp[i] + 1) * sizeof(struct word));
    }

    struct word word[spaces + periods];

    int start = 0, k = 0, wordsub = 0, sensub = 0, parasub = 0, docsub = 0, wordno = 0, parano = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++) {

        if(text[i] == ' ' || text[i] == '.') {
            word[wordsub].data = malloc((i - start) * sizeof(char) + 1);

            for(int j = start; j < i; j++)
                word[wordsub].data[k++] = text[j];

            word[wordsub].data[k++] = '\0';

            k = 0;

            if(i < strlen(text) - 1 && text[i + 1] == '\n')
                start = i + 2;
            else
                start = i + 1;

            if(text[i] == ' ') {

                sen[sensub].data[wordno] = word[wordsub];

                wordno++; //wordno can be 0 or 1
            }
            if(i != strlen(text) - 1 && isalpha(text[i + 1]) && text[i] == '.') {
                sen[sensub].data[wordno] = word[wordsub];

                wordno = 0;
                para[parasub].data[parano] = sen[sensub];
                sensub++;
                parano++;
            }
            if( (i != strlen(text) - 1 && text[i + 1] == '\n') || i  == strlen(text) - 1) {
                sen[sensub].data[wordno] = word[wordsub];
                wordno = 0;


                para[parasub].data[parano++] = sen[sensub];
                parano = 0;
                doc.data[docsub++] = para[parasub];
                parasub++;
                sensub++;

            }
            wordsub++;
        }
    }


    return doc;
}

struct word kth_word_in_mth_sentence_of_nth_paragraph(struct document Doc, int k, int m, int n) {
    return Doc.data[n - 1].data[m - 1].data[k - 1];
}

struct sentence kth_sentence_in_mth_paragraph(struct document Doc, int k, int m) {
    return Doc.data[m - 1].data[k - 1];
}

struct paragraph kth_paragraph(struct document Doc, int k) {

    return Doc.data[k - 1];
}


void print_word(struct word w) {
    printf("%s", w.data);
}

void print_sentence(struct sentence sen) {
    for(int i = 0; i < sen.word_count; i++) {
        print_word(sen.data[i]);
        if (i != sen.word_count - 1) {
            printf(" ");
        }
    }
}

void print_paragraph(struct paragraph para) {
    for(int i = 0; i < para.sentence_count; i++){
        print_sentence(para.data[i]);

        printf(".");

    }


}

void print_document(struct document doc) {
    for(int i = 0; i < doc.paragraph_count; i++) {
        print_paragraph(doc.data[i]);
        if (i != doc.paragraph_count - 1)
            printf("\n");
    }
}

char* get_input_text() {
    int paragraph_count;
    scanf("%d", &paragraph_count);

    char p[MAX_PARAGRAPHS][MAX_CHARACTERS], doc[MAX_CHARACTERS];
    memset(doc, 0, sizeof(doc));
    getchar();
    for (int i = 0; i < paragraph_count; i++) {
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", p[i]);
        strcat(doc, p[i]);
        if (i != paragraph_count - 1)
            strcat(doc, "\n");
    }

    char* returnDoc = (char*)malloc((strlen (doc)+1) * (sizeof(char)));
    strcpy(returnDoc, doc);
    return returnDoc;
}

int main()
{
    char* text = get_input_text();
    struct document Doc = get_document(text);

    int q;
    scanf("%d", &q);

    while (q--) {
        int type;
        scanf("%d", &type);

        if (type == 3){
            int k, m, n;
            scanf("%d %d %d", &k, &m, &n);
            struct word w = kth_word_in_mth_sentence_of_nth_paragraph(Doc, k, m, n);
            print_word(w);
        }

        else if (type == 2) {
            int k, m;
            scanf("%d %d", &k, &m);
            struct sentence sen= kth_sentence_in_mth_paragraph(Doc, k, m);
            print_sentence(sen);
        }

        else{
            int k;
            scanf("%d", &k);
            struct paragraph para = kth_paragraph(Doc, k);
            print_paragraph(para);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Single-step through the code with your debugger until you find the line where it crashes.

Comment: Please try to make it a minimum compilable verifiable example.

Comment: When you write outside the bounds of an array one possible outcome (**absolutely not guaranteed unreliable**) is that you overwrite another variable. See, for example, https://ideone.com/C78EV5

Comment: GDB and Valgrind are your best friends in such case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#define MAX_CHARACTERS 1005
#define MAX_PARAGRAPHS 5

struct word {
    char* data;
};

struct sentence {
    struct word* data;
    int word_count;//denotes number of words in a sentence
};

struct paragraph {
    struct sentence* data  ;
    int sentence_count;//denotes number of sentences in a paragraph
};

struct document {
    struct paragraph* data;
    int paragraph_count;//denotes number of paragraphs in a document
};
#include <ctype.h>
struct document get_document(char* text) {


    int spaces = 0, periods = 0, newlines = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
        if(text[i] == ' ')
            spaces++;
        else if(text[i] == '.')
            periods++;
        else if(text[i] == '\n')
            newlines++;


    struct document doc;
    doc.paragraph_count = newlines + 1;
    doc.data = malloc((newlines + 1) * sizeof(struct paragraph));

    int inBetweenPeriods = 0, j = 0;
    struct paragraph para[doc.paragraph_count];
    for(int i = 0; i < doc.paragraph_count; i++) {
        for(; j < strlen(text);)
            if(text[j] == '.')
            { inBetweenPeriods++;j++;}
            else if(text[j] == '\n' || j == strlen(text) - 1)
            {j++;break;}else j++;
        para[i].sentence_count = inBetweenPeriods;
        para[i].data = malloc((inBetweenPeriods) * sizeof(struct sentence));
        inBetweenPeriods = 0;
    }

    struct sentence sen[periods];
    int sp[periods];
    for(int j = 0; j < periods; j++)
        sp[j] = 0;
    int beg = 0;
    int ij = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < strlen(text); j++) {
        if(text[j] == '.') {
            for(int k = beg; k < j; k++)
                if(text[k] == ' ')
                    sp[ij]++;
            ij++;
            beg = j + 1;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < periods; i++) {

        sen[i].word_count = sp[i] + 1;//spaces + 1;
        sen[i].data = malloc((sp[i] + 1) * sizeof(struct word));
    }

    struct word word[spaces + periods];

    int start = 0, k = 0, wordsub = 0, sensub = 0, parasub = 0, docsub = 0, wordno = 0, parano = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++) {

        if(text[i] == ' ' || text[i] == '.') {
            word[wordsub].data = malloc((i - start) * sizeof(char) + 1);

            for(int j = start; j < i; j++)
                word[wordsub].data[k++] = text[j];

            word[wordsub].data[k++] = '\0';

            k = 0;

            if(i < strlen(text) - 1 && text[i + 1] == '\n')
                start = i + 2;
            else
                start = i + 1;

            if(text[i] == ' ') {

                sen[sensub].data[wordno] = word[wordsub];

                wordno++; //wordno can be 0 or 1
            }
            if(i != strlen(text) - 1 && isalpha(text[i + 1]) && text[i] == '.') {
                sen[sensub].data[wordno] = word[wordsub];

                wordno = 0;
                para[parasub].data[parano] = sen[sensub];
                sensub++;
                parano++;
            }
            if( (i != strlen(text) - 1 && text[i + 1] == '\n') || i  == strlen(text) - 1) {
                sen[sensub].data[wordno] = word[wordsub];
                wordno = 0;


                para[parasub].data[parano++] = sen[sensub];
                parano = 0;
                doc.data[docsub++] = para[parasub];
                parasub++;
                sensub++;

            }
            wordsub++;
        }
    }


    return doc;
}

struct word kth_word_in_mth_sentence_of_nth_paragraph(struct document Doc, int k, int m, int n) {
    return Doc.data[n - 1].data[m - 1].data[k - 1];
}

struct sentence kth_sentence_in_mth_paragraph(struct document Doc, int k, int m) {
    return Doc.data[m - 1].data[k - 1];
}

struct paragraph kth_paragraph(struct document Doc, int k) {

    return Doc.data[k - 1];
}


void print_word(struct word w) {
    printf("%s", w.data);
}

void print_sentence(struct sentence sen) {
    for(int i = 0; i < sen.word_count; i++) {
        print_word(sen.data[i]);
        if (i != sen.word_count - 1) {
            printf(" ");
        }
    }
}

void print_paragraph(struct paragraph para) {
    for(int i = 0; i < para.sentence_count; i++){
        print_sentence(para.data[i]);

        printf(".");

    }


}

void print_document(struct document doc) {
    for(int i = 0; i < doc.paragraph_count; i++) {
        print_paragraph(doc.data[i]);
        if (i != doc.paragraph_count - 1)
            printf("\n");
    }
}

char* get_input_text() {
    int paragraph_count;
    scanf("%d", &paragraph_count);

    char p[MAX_PARAGRAPHS][MAX_CHARACTERS], doc[MAX_CHARACTERS];
    memset(doc, 0, sizeof(doc));
    getchar();
    for (int i = 0; i < paragraph_count; i++) {
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", p[i]);
        strcat(doc, p[i]);
        if (i != paragraph_count - 1)
            strcat(doc, "\n");
    }

    char* returnDoc = (char*)malloc((strlen (doc)+1) * (sizeof(char)));
    strcpy(returnDoc, doc);
    return returnDoc;
}

int main()
{
    char* text = get_input_text();
    struct document Doc = get_document(text);

    int q;
    scanf("%d", &q);

    while (q--) {
        int type;
        scanf("%d", &type);

        if (type == 3){
            int k, m, n;
            scanf("%d %d %d", &k, &m, &n);
            struct word w = kth_word_in_mth_sentence_of_nth_paragraph(Doc, k, m, n);
            print_word(w);
        }

        else if (type == 2) {
            int k, m;
            scanf("%d %d", &k, &m);
            struct sentence sen= kth_sentence_in_mth_paragraph(Doc, k, m);
            print_sentence(sen);
        }

        else{
            int k;
            scanf("%d", &k);
            struct paragraph para = kth_paragraph(Doc, k);
            print_paragraph(para);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```